# Tag filter into Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I want to filter tags based on prefixes. Suppose I have tags as filter-material-woolen,filter-material-woolen1,filter-febric-velvet,filter-febric-velvet1. So I have to filter tag which have prefix "filter-"  and mid key word like "material,febric" will go as heading and final key will go as value.

```
<h1>material</h1>
<p>woolen1,woolen</p>

<h1>febric</h1>
<p>velvet,velvet1</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
        {% if tag contains 'filter-' %}
            <li>{{ tag | remove: 'filter-material-' | remove: 'filter-febric-' | link_to_tag: tag }}</li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: This will remove the material and fabric. I want material and fabric as heading and then values. Only filter prefix needs to be removed. In future, if any dynamic key is added like "filter-test-test1" then 

test will be heading like <h1>test</h1> and then value test1.

Basically, we need to filter by prefix then group by mid key and loop the values(last key)